# Get device signal strength

Tags: ios, iphone, 3g, iphone-privateapi, 4g

I am trying to get the signal strength in dBm for the carrier, wifi, 3g, and 4g.

I am currently using this code to get the carrier's and wifi from the status bar and I would like to know if there is another way or a better way? Also how could I get it for 3g and 4g?

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSArray *subviews = [[[app valueForKey:@"statusBar"] valueForKey:@"foregroundView"] subviews];
NSString *dataNetworkItemView = nil;
NSString *wifiNetworkItemView = nil;

for (id subview in subviews) {
    if([subview isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"UIStatusBarSignalStrengthItemView") class]]) {
        dataNetworkItemView = subview;
    }
    if([subview isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"UIStatusBarDataNetworkItemView") class]]) {
        wifiNetworkItemView = subview;
    }
}

int carrierSignalStrength = [[dataNetworkItemView valueForKey:@"signalStrengthRaw"] intValue];
int wifiSignalStrength = [[wifiNetworkItemView valueForKey:@"wifiStrengthRaw"] intValue];
```

It doesn't matter if any methods I use are private or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CoreTelephony and `CTTelephonyCenter` observers:

```
#include <CoreTelephony/CoreTelephony.h>

// Event handler
static void SignalStrengthDidChange(CFNotificationCenterRef center, void *observer, CFStringRef name, const void *object, CFDictionaryRef userInfo)
{
    long int raw = 0;
    long int graded = 0;
    long int bars = 0;

    CTIndicatorsGetSignalStrength(&raw, &graded, &bars);

    printf("Signal strength changed! Raw: %li, graded: %li bars: %li\n", raw, graded, bars);
    // Prints something like:
    // Signal strength changed! Raw: -96, graded: 27 bars: 3
}
```

Register the handler in another function:

```
// Register as a listener to the kCTIndicatorsSignalStrengthNotification notification to be notified when the signal strength changed.
CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver(CTTelephonyCenterGetDefault(), NULL, SignalStrengthDidChange, kCTIndicatorsSignalStrengthNotification, NULL, CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorCoalesce);

// Get the initial strength.
SignalStrengthDidChange();

CFRunLoopRun();
```

Adapted from the [iPhone Dev Wiki article on CTIndicators](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/CTIndicators).

These methods are no longer in any iOS SDKs greater than 8.4 (?) I believe.  To access them, create a new header with to extern the functions and constants:

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

#if __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#pragma mark - API

    /* This API is a mimic of CFNotificationCenter. */

    CFNotificationCenterRef CTTelephonyCenterGetDefault();
    void CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterRef center, const void *observer, CFNotificationCallback callBack, CFStringRef name, const void *object, CFNotificationSuspensionBehavior suspensionBehavior);
    void CTTelephonyCenterRemoveObserver(CFNotificationCenterRef center, const void *observer, CFStringRef name, const void *object);
    void CTTelephonyCenterRemoveEveryObserver(CFNotificationCenterRef center, const void *observer);

    void CTIndicatorsGetSignalStrength(long int *raw, long int *graded, long int *bars);

#pragma mark - Definitions

    /* For use with the CoreTelephony notification system. */
    extern CFStringRef kCTIndicatorsSignalStrengthNotification;

#if __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you! And do you think this would be considered private? Because it would be even better if this would would be acceptable for the appStore

Comment: This is definitely a private API.  To get this to compile on a modern SDK I had to manually extern some of the `CoreTelephony` constants and functions.  I'll edit my answer to include these declarations.

Comment: @JAL I want to get received signal strength of WiFi networks nearby. Can I use the above code for it? Is there any restriction eg. jailbroken device or iOS version for it? Thanks.

Comment: In iOS 12: Signal strength changed! Raw: 0, graded: 100 bars: 0 .

Answer (score 0):

I use private APIs too.. But I get this Signal strength from the (visible) Status bar.

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSArray *subviews = [[[app valueForKey:@"statusBar"] valueForKey:@"foregroundView"] subviews];
NSString *dataNetworkItemView = nil;
NSString *signalStrengthView = nil;

for (id subview in subviews) {
    NSLog(@"Class - %@", NSStringFromClass([subview class]));

    if([subview isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"UIStatusBarSignalStrengthItemView") class]]) {
        signalStrengthView = subview;
    }

    if([subview isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"UIStatusBarDataNetworkItemView") class]]) {
        dataNetworkItemView = subview;
    }
}

int signalStrength = [[signalStrengthView valueForKey:@"signalStrengthRaw"] intValue];
NSLog(@"signal %d", signalStrength);

int wifiStrength = [[dataNetworkItemView valueForKey:@"wifiStrengthRaw"] intValue];
NSLog(@"wifi %d", wifiStrength);
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: In iOS 12 carrier signal is 0.