# GSM Sensor data gathering iPhone

Tags: ios, gsm

for a personal project I need to collect near GSM stations signal strength with the iPhone sensor. How can I access those data? Does Apple provide any framework like CMMotion for raw data coming accelerometer, gyroscope, etc.?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Measuring cellular signal strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954389/measuring-cellular-signal-strength)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any officially supported API to allow you do this.

There are some techniques using private API's to do this - see this answer for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40140991/334402

This approach may be ok for you if it is for a personal project.